# How can I make a map object global?

Tags: javascript

I want to make a global variable to be used not only by one object how can I do it?

```
//Want to take the type of str and myVar
str.type
myVar.type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't use the keyword `var` and it will be global, but that will not make it the property of the Object. I would just assign the Object property to a variable outside the Object, then it can be inherited by all Objects below, like:

```
function Obj(val){
  this.prop = val;
}
var obj = new Obj('nice'), whatever = obj.prop;
// now whatever is accessible to other Objects below
```